# verify digital signature pdf java IText

Tags: java, security, itext, signature, verify

I was trying to validate the signature I added to a pdf file with IText with my token but I got some errors:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)
```

This is my code:

```
//verifying pdf signatures
public PdfPKCS7 verifySignature(AcroFields fields, String name) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Signature covers whole document: " + fields.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name));
    System.out.println("Document revision: " + fields.getRevision(name) + " of " + fields.getTotalRevisions());
    PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.verifySignature(name);
    System.out.println("Integrity check OK? " + pkcs7.verify());
    return pkcs7;
}

public void verifySignatures(String path) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    System.out.println(path);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
    AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields();
    ArrayList<String> names = fields.getSignatureNames();
    for (String name : names) {
        System.out.println("===== " + name + " =====");
        verifySignature(fields, name);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This is the whole log:

```
===== sig_2 =====
Signature covers whole document: true
Document revision: 1 of 1
Exception in thread "main" ExceptionConverter: 
java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)
at java.security.Signature$Delegate.chooseProvider(Unknown Source)
at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitVerify(Unknown Source)
at java.security.Signature.initVerify(Unknown Source)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7.<init>(PdfPKCS7.java:452)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields.verifySignature(AcroFields.java:2317)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields.verifySignature(AcroFields.java:2270)
at com.pdf.sign.Main.verifySignature(Main.java:91)
at com.pdf.sign.Main.verifySignatures(Main.java:103)
at com.pdf.sign.Main.main(Main.java:147)
```

Comment: Can you post the whole log and stacktrace?

Comment: Which iText 5 version do you use? Considering your stack trace it appears not to be a current one. Furthermore, can you share your sample signed file?

Comment: Furthermore, have you added BouncyCastle to your class path? Which version? Have you registered it as security provider? (Your stack trace effectively says that the public key from the signer certificate is `null` which is weird.)

Comment: Any responses to my clarification requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your keystore doesn't seem to get initialized, and so your key is null.

For examples of usage, I found this: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.0.6/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.java#AcroFields.verifySignature%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29

There you can also see source code and find where and why the exception is thrown.

Comment: The current version of iText 5 is 5.5.13. The version 5.0.6 for which you found some code is ancient, the iText signature API has changed considerably since then.

Comment: You're right, but the version he's using seems to be closer to this one rather than the latest one, as far as I can tell. If he specified his exact version, I would update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with Bouncy Castle (see https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/144). You need to add the following line before checking the PDF signature

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I had forgotten to add the provier